# locate the source files for android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit, appium

I'm an intern and I'm new to automation. I am trying to familiarize myself with the mobile application automation tool 'appium'. I'm running a windows machine. I found a few sample appium tests using junit [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/tree/master/sample-code/examples/java/junit/src/test/java/com/saucelabs/appium). these tests are for the built-in android / iOS apps, for now I am only concerned with the android ones. I do realize that these apps where written on a MAC machine and I have changed it for my windows machine.

My Issue, however, is to find the .apk's locations for the built in apps on the eclipse emulator so that I can use it in my test.

I hope I've provided enough information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific as to what you are looking for: .apk files?  If so the installed ones, or the MAC/PC files that were installed?  Source code for locally developed projects?  Source code for the apps that ship on an emulator image?  Source code for the emulator image's frameworks?  Its kernel?  The emulation engine itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in this location on mac:

```
/Users/<username>/.android/avd/
```

There should be 2 files for each emulator you created, *.avd and *.ini

You can always run the manager for the emulators by doing on the terminal:

```
/<path_to_android_sdk>/android avd
```

This should list all the emulators you have created. If you cant do via terminal just find the android exe and see if you can open the avd manager via the GUI.
Not sure about windows but my guess would be a hidden folder with the same type of files. Try a global search or some local user directory. I had to manually delete an emulator when it started acting up and those files did the trick.